# Taking Protein Shake with BCAA tablets?

Tags: supplements, protein-shakes

Is it okay to take this together with green tea and caffeine?

Comment: Uhm, what is your question - "is it ok to take protein shake with BCAA pils" or "is it ok to take proteins (and BCAA) with green tea and caffeine"?

Comment: Also, unless you can relate it to your own fitness goals, this is a straight nutrition question which is off topic for the site. http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I'd like to see a definition of "okay" - okay for what? What are you concerned about? Please edit the question per these comments and I think it will garner better answers (and have a better shot to stay open). BTW, welcome to fitness.se! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no allergies to the products and can tolerate the caffeine, I wouldn't expect there to be any significant detriment to your health from that mixture. That said, it's generally advisable to dose supplements and meal replacements separately. In your particular case, the following issues arise:

1. BCAA absorption might be sub-optimal, as they'll compete for uptake with the proteins you ingest.
2. There's some evidence that aspects of the health benefits of green tea are abrogated by co-administration of milk. This effect is attributed specifically to the presence of casein protein, and might reasonably be expected to occur with other types of protein as well. In essence, the protein binds to and forms chemical complexes with some of the salutary constituents of the tea, namely the various phenolic antioxidants. Other studies cast doubt on this purported effect, but it's probably prudent to avoid the possibility altogether.<sup>[1][2]</sup>

References:

1. http://eurheartj.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2007/01/09/eurheartj.ehl442
2. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21692489